# AWS S3 + Route53: Redirecto S3 bucket not doing anything

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a domain: `mydomain.com`.

I've created an `A` record for `www.mydomain.com` with an alias targeting the load balancer's DNS and works just fine:

> When I hit `www.mydomain.com` everything works fine.

Now, I want to redirect all requests to **mydomain.com** to **www.mydomain.com** (Note the **www** prefix).
So I created an S3 bucket named `mydomain.com` with a redirection to `www.mydomain.com`, and an A record for `mydomain.com` with an alias targeting the S3 bucket named `mydomain.com` I just created.

The idea here is to make all requests to `mydomain.com` to go to my S3 bucket and then get redirected to `www.mydomain.com`.

> But when I go to `mydomain.com`, the browser just keeps loading forever. No redirection seems to be happening.

All I want is to redirect requests to `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`, how can I make this work? Why is my browser loading forever and not giving any error?

Comment: Hey Daniel did you add www.mydomain.com as an A record pointing to the ELB in Route53 HostedZone for mydomain.com

Comment: Hi David, yes I did, but still nothing :(

Comment: So two differences I have when I did this was 1. I had the redirection going from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (Which is what matches the Route53 HostedZone). 2. My A records are not pointing to an ELB they are using CloudFront. In the case of using the ELB it has its own public DNS perhaps the route53 bucket must redirect to that instead?